# powershell Import psd1 and use command?

Tags: powershell, centos

I'm trying to run some powershell scripts from a Centos box. I have installed powershell successfully and have then further obtained the scripts i wish to run.

in powershell i have run:

```
Import-PowershellDataFile ./tools/powershell/DhcpServer.psd1
```

Then i have tried to use:

```
Get-DhcpServerv4Scope -ComputerName 10.66.56.66
```

i have imported the following into my folder /tools/powershell:

```
DhcpServer.psd1
DhcpServerPSProvider.Format.ps1xml
PS_DhcpServerv4Lease_v1.0.0.cdxml
PS_DhcpServerV4Scope_v1.0.0.cdxml
```

Ive edited DhcpServer.psd1 to remove all functions other than Get-DhcpServerv4Scope and Get-DhcpServerv4Lease, these are the only two i need for this tool.

heres the output of my attempt:

```
PS /root/itapp> Import-PowershellDataFile ./tools/powershell/DhcpServer.psd1

Name                           Value
----                           -----
TypesToProcess                 DhcpServerPsProvider.Types.PS1XML
ClrVersion                     4.0
NestedModules                  {PS_DhcpServerv4Lease_v1.0.0.cdxml, PS_DhcpServerV4Scope_v1.0.0.cdxml}
Author                         Microsoft Corporation
CompanyName                    Microsoft Corporation
Copyright                      Â© Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
FunctionsToExport              {Get-DhcpServerv4Scope, Get-DhcpServerv4Lease}
FormatsToProcess               DhcpServerPsProvider.Format.ps1xml
HelpInfoUri                    http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=285742
GUID                           90eaa9df-133a-450c-8728-91055cd946a1
ModuleVersion                  2.0.0.0
PowerShellVersion              3.0


PS /root/itapp> Get-DhcpServerv4Scope -ComputerName 10.66.56.66
Get-DhcpServerv4Scope : The term 'Get-DhcpServerv4Scope' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-DhcpServerv4Scope -ComputerName 10.10.10.10
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-DhcpServerv4Scope:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS /root/itapp>
```

can anyone help me out?
Thanks

Comment: I believe ,you should use import-module for the psd1 file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .psd1 file is the Module Manifest file. There should also be a .psm1 file that contains the code (unless it's a compiled module).

To load the module you need to use:

```
Import-Module ./tools/powershell/DhcpServer.psd1
```

The `Import-PowershellDataFile` just reads the contents of the datafile in to a hashtable, it doesn't load the functions/cmdlets.

Comment: thanks, that did it, i have other errors now but ill research those first